# Looking for a Table of Contents (TOC) plugin for WordPress

Tags: plugins, customization

I am looking for a simple TOC plugin for WordPress that would create a ToC similar to the one from MediaWiki (Wikipedia). Usually I need this only for big pages and the TOC needs to be generated based on heading from the post.

Considering that the number of pages need TOC is quite small, it should be ok to enable this plugin only for some of them.

I found several solutions, but none of them seamed ok. The closest one was Hackadelic SEO Table Of Contents, but this one had two big issues: contained a AD link and no way to enable it only for specific pages.

Answer (score 5):

check out this one http://scott.yang.id.au/code/toc-generator/

seems to answer your requirements.

### Update

after reading the comment i figured that i could take a crack at it and i came up with this:

[**Simple TOC**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bainternet-simple-toc/) enjoy!

no style is implemented so you can do what ever you want with it with the provided classes.
enjoy.

Comment: This is quite old (2006) and has some annoying bugs. I’ve used it but wouldn’t recommend it anymore.

Comment: @toscho: i guess i've jump with an answer and yeah its not that good, so i cooked a quick one.

Comment: It would be ok with one remark, there is no reason for using special tags instead of detecting HTML heading elements.

Comment: No, but i was aiming at a wiki like markup.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give [Table of Contents Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/table-of-contents-plus/) a try. The TOC is added automatically, but you can choose the minimum number of headings. You can make some customisation in the behaviour and choose different styles.