# Adding a Nav menu to post admin

Tags: posts, custom-field, menus, post-editor

i want insert a dropdown menu with list of menus, that i've created in nav-menu.php, to post-admin...

For example, when i'm creating a post, i want insert a menu "Paul" in a post (only a post that i want) selecting a menu at right sidebar of Admin-Post.

I've copied the rows:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'primary-menu' => __( 'Primary Menu' ),
            'personal-menu' => __( 'Personal Menu' )
        )
    );
}
```

in a post.fields.php that i've created, don't work. :(

[Link to existing code](http://www.francescomarullo.com/postfieldsphp.zip).

Can you help me in that fantastic problem? :(

ps: Sorry for my bad english

Francesco

Comment: I made an update to my answer and included a filter function you can use.

Answer (score 4):

To see how such a list can be created look at the code in `wp-admin/includes/nav-menu.php`. Unfortunately, it is hard coded there, so you have to re-create the code.

First, let’s create [two menus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNTme.jpg):

[image]

We can get these menus in PHP with [`wp_get_nav_menus()`](http://xref.yoast.com/trunk/wp-includes/nav-menu.php.source.html#l401) (a wrapper for [`get_terms()`](http://xref.yoast.com/trunk/wp-includes/taxonomy.php.source.html#l1051)):

```
$menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
print '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars( print_r( $menus, TRUE ) ) . '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 5
            [name] => Paradigmatic Inconvenience
            [slug] => paradigmatic-inconvenience
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 5
            [taxonomy] => nav_menu
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [term_id] => 6
            [name] => Paul
            [slug] => paul
            [term_group] => 0
            [term_taxonomy_id] => 6
            [taxonomy] => nav_menu
            [description] => 
            [parent] => 0
            [count] => 0
        )
)
```

Now we build the selector function:

```
/**
 * Build a dropdown selector for all existing nav menus.
 *
 * @author Thomas Scholz, toscho.de
 * @param  string $name     Used as name attribute for the select element.
 * @param  string $selected Slug of the selected menu
 * @param  bool   $print    Print output or just return the HTML.
 * @return string
 */
function t5_nav_menu_drop_down( $name, $selected = '', $print = TRUE )
{
    // array of menu objects
    $menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
    $out   = '';

    // No menu found.
    if ( empty ( $menus ) or is_a( $menus, 'WP_Error' )  )
    {
        // Give some feedback …
        $out .= __( 'There are no menus.', 't5_nav_menu_per_post' );

        // … and make it usable …
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_theme_options' ) )
        {
            $out .= sprintf(
                __( ' <a href="%s">Create one</a>.', 't5_nav_menu_per_post' ),
                admin_url( 'nav-menus.php' )
            );
        }
        // … and stop.
        $print and print $out;
        return $out;
    }

    // Set name and ID to let you use a <label for='id_$name'>
    $out = "<select name='$name' id='id_$name'>\n";

    foreach ( $menus as $menu )
    {
        // Preselect the active menu
        $active = $selected == $menu->slug ? 'selected' : '';
        // Show the description
        $title  = empty ( $menu->description ) ? '' : esc_attr( $menu->description );

        $out .= "\t<option value='$menu->slug' $active $title>$menu->name</option>\n";
    }

    $out .= '</select>';

    $print and print $out;
    return $out;
}
```

Calling this function …

```
t5_nav_menu_drop_down( 'my_nav_select', 'paul' );
```

… will give us a nice, simple select element with `'paul'` pre-selected:

[image]

Now we need a meta box to offer the selector to our post authors. To keep this short, I just use a child class of my [Basic Meta Box](https://gist.github.com/1748108). Basically, you call the function in the meta box and save the menu slug as post meta.

[image]

Then you can access the selected **nav menu slug** in your theme per:

```
get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_t5_nav_menu_per_post', TRUE );
```

Another way to get the **full nav menu** in your theme:

```
// Print a wp_nav_menu
do_action( 
    't5_custom_nav_menu', 
    // an array of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
    array ( 
        'menu' => 'default-menu',
        // you may set a custom post ID
        'post_id' => get_the_ID() 
    ) 
);
```

---

Because I like your idea very much I’ve added a theme helper function and mangled everything into a plugin. Get it on GitHub: [T5 Nav Menu Per Post](https://github.com/toscho/T5-Nav-Menu-Per-Post).

Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange. Don’t worry about your English as long as you ask – and answer – interesting questions. :)

### Update

To use the plugin with a custom post type like your `portfolio` just install the plugin, activate it and add the following code to the file where you register the custom post type:

```
add_filter( 't5_nav_menu_per_post_post_types', 'wpse41695_add_post_type' );

function wpse41695_add_post_type( $post_types )
{
    $post_types[] = 'portfolios';
    return $post_types;
}
```

Your code still has many problems: global variables, missing prefixes, weird indentation. Recommended reading: [Coding Standards](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards) and [prefix everything](http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/).

Comment: Pretty kool! +1

Comment: Ok, it work and the one of these problem is: i see the dropmenu everywhere, in admin pages and themes :S :D
And the second problem: how can i put in the box at the right of Portfolio? so: i called the t5_nav_menu_drop_down( 'my_nav_select', 'paul' );, but how can i put in the box? with Basic Meta Box? and how? :( sorry for nooby :(

Comment: Yes, i've resolved, simply: i paste your code (the add_filter) in the php of your plugin Nav Menu Per Post :)....

Comment: Ops, i passed 5 minutes because i want edit my last comment...so, i've two problem for theme: how can i get the code? i've put the code get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_t5_nav_menu_per_post', TRUE ); in the post.php but don't work...and the second: how can i put the class and id in this custom nav? thank you very much! :)

Comment: And the third problem : if i save the portfolio (ONLY THE CUSTOM PORTFOLIO, because with the post/article it work!), it no remain selected...it return to "Pick one"...how can i resolve? thank you more! :(

Comment: @user12932 I’ve added an example call for a full nav menu in your theme. To set more values for the menu just use the regular `wp_nav_menu()` arguments. See [this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19247/73) for details. Not sure why it doesn’t save the menu on your custom post type … maybe a conflict with your other meta boxes?

Comment: probably yes...i will check...see you later for more problems (if...i hope no :D)

Comment: Nada, don't work... i don't know to how it work to get the menu that i've selected trought amdin-portfolio :(... i tried with wp_nav_menu and insert into array the _t5_nav_menu_per_post...but don't work...can you help me? :(...and the second problem...it don't work with the Save...i've deleted the other metaboxes..but don't work...

Comment: Ohhhh perfect! i've resolve...i haven't use this row: <?php do_action( 't5_custom_nav_menu', array ( 'menu' => 'default-menu' );?> and i've added the classe and id... :) i'm so happy...ok, perfect...but it work only the default editor post...and don't work with the editor portfolio (the custom editor post)...how can i resolve? this is the famous last problem! :) ps: i hope that this discussion can be useful for all people! :)

Comment: @user12932 Do you use the filter? The last code block in my answer. The added post type therein `'portfolios'` has to match exactly your custom post type.

Comment: yes, i pasted in you plugin nav for post, the page is t5-nav-per-post.php...but thank to this, i see in the portfolios-editor...but it cannot save...it return to "pick one"...and the name is exact!

Comment: Hi, I've seen more codes online for save a post..but don't work :(..uff..this problem is very big...:(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem regarding the custom post_type not saving the data. It was due to it failing `save_allowed()` in `basic_meta_box.php`.

`current_user_can('edit_'.$_POST['post_type'],$post_id)` which with a custom post type resolves to `current_user_can('edit_portfolio',$post_id)` - which fails in wordpress. need to change to a valid capability like `edit_others_pages` or `edit_pages`.