# Does codex.wordpress.org use a plugin of some sort? If so what plugin?

Tags: plugins, wiki, codex

I'm attempting to set up a wiki within a Wordpress install and love the way codex.wordpress.org is set up.  Are they using a specific plugin to accomplish that or just well structured pages?  Is there a similar plugin available to users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi in the wordpress.org header is this:

```
<meta name="generator" content="MediaWiki 1.15.5" />
```

which leads me to think that it is this that is used

[**MediaWiki**](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)

regards
Martin

edit: something similar was aked before and it looks like a plugin solution was found
[**Plugin Similar To MediaWiki**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16046/looking-for-a-table-of-contents-toc-plugin-for-wordpress) by Bainternet

Comment: That is almost correct :) my plugin only generates a TOC in a MediaWiki like manner, but not any wiki functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Just like Martin said, Wordpress codex uses [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki)
but i'm posting a two plugins that will let you set up a wiki within WordPress sites:

- [**Wiki lite**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-wiki-plugin/) - from the guys at wpmudev.
- [**WordPress Wiki**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-wiki/) - from the guys at Instinct.