# Make a navigation menu in the same post

Tags: menus, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a Table of Contents (TOC) plugin for WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16046/looking-for-a-table-of-contents-toc-plugin-for-wordpress)

I have been trying for some time to do one thing: I need a navigation menu inside a Wordpress post which will guide the user to different subsections of my post, and then maybe use a "Top" button to go back to the top. Let me give you an example:

Title

Introduction "jnkdjajkfa"

Menu

*Section one - this is a link*

*Section two - this is a link*

*Conclusion - this is a link*

**Section one**
"bdsjkbdfsjbfjkasbjkbfasbjf"

*Back to top - this is a link*

**Section two** 
"dnjsdkfhbsjukfbajfkbjkfbkasbfjk"

*Back to top - this is a link*

**Conclusion**
"ndjasndkasnj"

*Back to top - this is a link*

I know I can do this in the code, but it's really a pain to do it on every post. Do you know a plugin, method to easily do this? Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for "[Table of Contents](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/16046/2110)" feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put The code in the php file in your theme.If you use twentyeleven theme open content-single.php, find the line

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

And after it put your divs and top menu.

## Another option is to create a widget where you could easily update the html code.

Instead your divs,  below this line

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
```

paste this:

```
<?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar( 'links-below-post-title' ) ) : ?>
```

Also in fuctions.php after

```
function twentyeleven_widgets_init() {
```

add this:

```
register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Links Below Post Title', 'twentyeleven' ),
        'id' => 'links-below-post-title',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => "",
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ) );
```

Comment: And what do I do if I want to have more than a fixed number of sub-menus? Your idea is good, but I would need something a bit more dynamic. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Daniel I updated the answer.I hope html in widget is dynamic enough :) .It even says "dynamic_sidebar" in the code, so it must be so ;D

Comment: I will try it out just now and will get back to you. I can't quite understand everything, but I'll come back as I work on the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I have actually made myself clear on this one. What I actually want is a menu inside the post as the one you can see here: http://shapeasmile.com/gifts-for-twins-%E2%80%93-top-4-items-for-babies/ . I hope I can post links as examples. But I wanted to make it more dynamic, and not hardcoded. Your widget is nice (Thanks, I learned how to make a widget area), but it's just not showing up in my posts.

Comment: @Daniel go to wp admin add some content in the widget area and it must show up.I didn't tried it myself, but I've done exactly that with another theme and it worked fine.

In order to have a widget in the middle of the post try to use this example http://themeshaper.com/forums/topic/how-to-make-singe-insert-behave-like-index-insert#post-8907

Comment: @Tomas Correct me if I'm wrong but as I understand it Daniel wants to dynamically create something like TOC (Table of Contents) **based on the content of each post**. Simple (text) widget will display the same text whenever displayed.

Comment: @Maugly Maybe you are right.In this case the solution would be to find a suitable plugin or make one yourself or pay someone to do it, because the task is more complicated at least to my knowledge

Comment: @Maugly Yes, I wanted something like a TOC. I've almost solved it. It's more complicated than it seems, but it can be done with a high level of dynamism with the help of shortcodes. A main menu (TOC) which takes arguments and other shortcodes which when included put the <a name=""> code in the page. I'll come back as I work on it..but there's a little bit of digging to be done before making it work. Cheers!

Comment: @Daniel have you seen the answer to the (possibly duplicate) question I posted in the comment above at your question? It's a well done TOC plugin by our top member :)